# Using list as a data type in a column (SQLAlchemy)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to store a list of rss feed urls in an sqlite db. I'm using SQLAlchemy and was wondering how to store these. I can't seem to find any documentation about lists, and was wondering if this was legal for a column:
    Column('rss_feed_urls', List)

Or is there an array type that I could use?

Comment: If you were using PostgreSQL, it has array types, which you could use for this purpose. A 1 dim string array is essntially a list of strings.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you really must you could use the [PickleType](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.PickleType). But what you probably want is another table (which consists of a *list* of rows, right?). Just create a table to hold your RSS feeds:

```
class RssFeed(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'rssfeeds'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    url = Column(String)
```

Add new urls:

```
feed = RssFeed(url='http://url/for/feed')
session.add(feed)
```

Retrieve your list of urls:

```
session.query(RssFeed).all()
```

Find a specific feed by index:

```
session.query(RssFeed).get(1)
```

I'd recommend SQLAlchemy's [Object Relational Tutorial](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/tutorial/orm_related_objects.html).

Answer (score 20):

If you are using a PostgreSQL database, you can use the SQL Alchemy type [ARRAY](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.ARRAY) for that. Note that it is a typed Array.

```
class sqlalchemy.types.ARRAY(item_type, as_tuple=False, dimensions=None, zero_indexes=False)
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use `MutableList` from sqlalchemy

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.mutable import MutableList
from sqlalchemy import PickleType
import logging # not necessary, for logging purpose only

my_list_column_field = Column(MutableList.as_mutable(PickleType),
                                    default=[])

# now you can do common operations in this list. e.g:

# append to the list (just like python)
my_list_column_field = my_list_column_field + [any_data_type]

# and don't forget to commit your changes
try:
   db.commit()
except SQLAlchemyError as e:
   db.rollback()
   logging.error("Failed to Commit because of {error}. Doing Rollback".format(error=e))
```

If you simply use `PickleType`, you won't be able to modify that list after the first insert. To modify later we need `MutableList`. You can also use `Set, Dict` like this using `MutableSet, MutableDict`.

There is another less obvious way though. To save as String by `json.dumps(my_list)` and then while retrieving just do `json.loads(my_column)`. But it will require you to set the data in a key-value format and seems a bit in-efficient compared to the previous solution.

Answer (score 10):

There is normally no list among SQL database column data types.

One way to store a list as a column value is to convert that list to a string, that would map to database data type `varchar`.

Another way is to convert the list to a serialized binary representation (using [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) library, for example) and store the value as a database value of type `blob`.

Comment: Bleh I knew this wouldn't be easy. What exactly is the varchar type? The SQLAlchemy documentation doesn't elaborate.

Comment: See [sqlalchemy.types.LargeBinary](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/types.html#sqlalchemy.types.LargeBinary) and [sqlalchemy.types.String](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/types.html#sqlalchemy.types.String)