# SQLALCHEMY storing a list of string in a table

Tags: sqlalchemy

Using SQLAlchemy, I have to store a list of string values in a separate table. This separate table will contain only primary key of the first table and the list of string values.
How can I map this in the classical way? I cannot change the class as it is generated from xsd.

Comment: If you are using PostgreSQL you can store the values as a 1 dim array of strings i think. But it really depends on exactly what you are trying to do. Give more details.

Comment: Are values stored in multiple rows, multiple columns or in "one row, one column" (examples: delimited list, XML, or so)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using list as a data type in a column (SQLAlchemy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300230/using-list-as-a-data-type-in-a-column-sqlalchemy)

Answer (score 1):

You have to add each entry for each element in your list. You can implement [One to Many](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationships.html#one-to-many)  relationship between these 2 tables.