# python using sqlalchemy store a list into sql database

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

The brief code is like this:

```
    class Word(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'word'
        eng                 = Column(String(32),primary_key=True)
        chinese             = Column(String(128))

word = Word(eng='art',chinese=[u'艺术',u'美术'])
session.add(word)
session.commit()
```

I'm trying to store word.chinese as a string. And in python it's a list...
Well, when I write sql myself I could str(word.chinese) and then insert into the database.
When need to get it, I could simply eval(result) to get the original python object.
But since I'm using the sqlalchemy to store my objects, I wonder where to change to reach my goal...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To store a list in a db you could use a new table:

```
class Word(Base):
    __tablename__ = "words"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    eng = Column(String(32), unique=True)
    chinese = relationship("Chinese", backref="eng")

    def __init__(self, eng, chinese):
        self.eng = eng
        self.chinese = map(Chinese, chinese)

class Chinese(Base):
    __tablename__ = "chinese_words"

    word = Column(String(128), primary_key=True)
    eng_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('words.id'), primary_key=True)

    def __init__(self, word):
        self.word = word
```

See [full example](https://gist.github.com/ad49f71aa86e8cbd65ea#file_model.py).

Don't use `str()`/`eval()` if you want to store `chinese` as a blob you could use `json.dumps()`/`json.loads()`. Using suggested by [@thebjorn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11915214/4279) `TypeDecorator`:

```
class Json(TypeDecorator):

    impl = String

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        return json.dumps(value)

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        return json.loads(value)

class Word(Base):
    __tablename__ = "words"

    eng = Column(String(32), primary_key=True)
    chinese = Column(Json(128))
```

See [full example](https://gist.github.com/ad49f71aa86e8cbd65ea#file_as_a_blob.py).

Comment: This is not related to the very good answer to the actual question, just a comment that having `unique=True` on `Word.eng` will prevent you from storing different translations for homographs (e.g. 'live' -- rhymes with 'give', and 'live' -- rhymes with 'dive').  A similar problem arises when two separate concepts in language A maps to a single concept in language B, e.g. German essen/fressen -> eat (depends on the subject), French savoir/connaître -> know (depends on the object), English roof/ceiling -> tak [Norwegian] (depends on...), etc.  Natural language translation is hard ;-)

Comment: @thebjorn: `Word.eng` is a primary key in the question that implies uniqueness. Disregarding it, I've used [**one to many** relationship](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationships.html#one-to-many) instead of [**many to many**](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationships.html#many-to-many) (what you've described) to avoid complicating the example that demonstrates how to store a list in db. Sqlalchemy supports it if you need it.

Answer (score 4):

You'll find the functionality you're asking for in `TypeDecorator` ( http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/types.html#sqlalchemy.types.TypeDecorator -- you'll have to create e.g. a subclass of list to get it to work).

**However,** what you're trying to do is store two different translations for the English word art (at least that's what google translate is telling me :-).  Storing them as a comma-separated list in a text field is not first normal form.  You should store two records

```
('art', u'艺术')
('art', u'美术')
```

and change your database structure to allow for this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that stringifying list doesn't work as you expected (my conclusion from your post). You can store chinese words in database, just instead of `str(word.chinese)`, make `u''.join(word.chinese)` and store value in database as a string.

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably want to refine your data schema a little more instead of performing unsightly manipulations from and to strings/lists in one of your model's attributes.

I am assuming that each `eng` can have 1 or more ´chinese´, in which case you want a 1 to many [relationship](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/tutorial.html#building-a-relationship) and two tables/mapped objects instead.

your code will be significantly cleaner.

`eval`'ing strings is just a really bad idea. Always.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question that deserves newer answers.

As of the year 2022, you can use MutableList from sqlalchemy, as shown in this answer: `https://stackoverflow.com/a/64356997/2719980`