# Inserting an array/dictionary/list in database (SQLite3, SQLAlchemy)

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

I have this model

```py
from sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes import ARRAY
from . import db 
from flask_login import UserMixin
from datetime import datetime
from sqlalchemy.types import ARRAY 

class Image(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = db.Column(db.String(100))
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), default=datetime.now())
    title = db.Column(db.String(150))
    description = db.Column(db.String(500))
    labels = db.Column(ARRAY(db.String(200)))
    quantity = db.Column(ARRAY(db.Integer))
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Image('{self.data}', '{self.date}')"

    def save_to_db(self):
        db.session.add(self)
        db.session.commit()
```

and i want to save labels and quantity as an array. Also the type of both is `list`
but for some reason sqlalchemy don't accept it.

I've also tried putting the `ARRAY` method from `sqlalchemy.types` but it throws again the same error

```py
sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
[SQL: UPDATE image SET labels=?, quantity=? WHERE image.id = ?]
[parameters: (['person'], '[1]', 1)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/rvf5)
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7300417/15011621). Another thing you can do is convert the list into string and then when accessing it convert it into list using .join() and .split() methods.

Comment: i did that actually, i've sort of stringify them and pass the output to an array, and now i want to pass the array to the database.

Comment: I don't think database has any datatype array or list. You can  define datatype as string and then while inserting you can do " ".join(list). When accessing you can do the following. list.split(" ").

Comment: alright i got you thank you so much