# Is it possible to store a list or a python dictionary in a sqlalchemy database column?

Tags: python, database, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm doing a grocery shop website and I'm still new to web dev. I'd like to add in my Users table a column that stores a list with all the user's purchase date or a dictionary with all the user's purchase date as keys and items as values. I'm using Flask-SQLAlchemy for my database. Is there a way to do this?
Here is my code:

```
class Users(db.Model):                              
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True, nullable=False)
    email_confirmed = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)
    email_confirmed_on = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), nullable=True)
    purchase_history = db.Column(??)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(120))
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why not just store the data normally, using a transaction table model?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using list as a data type in a column (SQLAlchemy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300230/using-list-as-a-data-type-in-a-column-sqlalchemy)

Answer (score 0):

There actually IS a way to store a list in database (as a JSON field), but it is strongly not recommended to do this (at least you really really need to) and you probably will be cursed by your colleagues. jk.

it is better to store such entities in a separate table.

not only because it's more read-usable (allowing you to filter purchases that will be displayed, for example), but also because it's easier to maintain. in fact, you already gave a good example yourself.

say, at the moment dates is all that's enough for you to store purchase history. so you store it as a list.
but then you decide you want to store items also.
and display them.
but you already store purchase history as a list, and it will be a huge headache to adjust it, especially if you have a lot of data already stored there.

I hope you get the idea. I'd create a `Purchase` table and a [relationship](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-many) for User.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).